# iPhone: How to remove all objects from a UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, subview

Basically I want to remove all objects from a UIScrollView and I haven't yet found a solution to it because a simple "removeAllObjects" command doesn't work. Does anyone have an idea how to do it?

Comment: Don't remove all the subviews of a `UISubview`. It's scroll indicator views are subviews. You will be removing those too. I recommend placing your content views in your own container UIView. (keep it as an ivar for easy access while adding and removing from it)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Even easier:

```
[[scrollView subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

Comment: i'm guessing you have the same issue with `makeObjectsPerformSelector` in regards to it looping through the subviews while modifying the array concurrently.  this way is elegant and used by many, but how do you address what progrmr brought up above?

Comment: I'm fairly sure makeObjectsPerformSelector: generates a temporary array before calling the selector on each object. If it didn't, as you say, it'd cause issues.

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way:

```
for(UIView *subview in [scrollView subviews]) {

    [subview removeFromSuperview];

}
```

Comment: Is it safe to modify the array contents while looping thru the elements?  I'm just wondering...

Comment: In general it is probably not the best practice, so you may want to set up a temporary array marked for removal. :P

Comment: It's definitely safe to remove subviews while enumerating parent's subviews collection

Answer (score 3):

Two solutions would be, without removing the scrollbars:

## Add a tag to all of your subviews, remove them by using those tags.

Implementation:

Place this above your class

```
#define XPScrollViewSubviewStartTag             100
```

When you add the objects

```
for(NSInteger = 0;i<[viewArray count];i++){
     UIView* view = [viewArray objectAtIndex:i];
     view.tag = XPScrollViewSubviewStartTag + i;
     [scrollView addSubview:view];
}
```

When you later want to delete the views use

```
for(UIView* view in [scrollView subviews]){
      if(view.tag >= XPScrollViewSubviewStartTag)
           [view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

## Create a custom UIView class

When you want to remove the views

```
for(id view in [scrollView subviews]){
      if(![view isKindOfClass:[CustomView class]])
            continue;

      //not necessary, but just to make things understandable
      CustomView* customView = (CustomView*)view;
      [customView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Oritm's solution is nice, but if you don't want to bother using tags, you can manually remove which views you want to remove from the scrollview. This will assume that you know which view to remove. For example, my scrollview only has UILabels so when I run the following:

```
// This will remove the scrollview but the scrollbars will remain 
for (UIView *subview in [self.detailsExpander.scrollView subviews]) {
    if ([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"UILabel"])
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
}
```

This will only remove all the labels but keep the scrollbars (which are image views). Note: this won't work if you want to keep specific image views while at the same time you want to keep the scrollbars.